# GUI Of Minesweeper

Tags: java, swing

how do you do the text for Jable i try this

```
 JLabel label = new JLabel ("Count !!", JLabel.CENTER);
 label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
 label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
 add (label);
```

but it always shows me the top left side. I don't know I try south, north it didn't work at all.

How do I put a flag on location that the user right click on it and put flag there. and how do I put an img to all mine in game board when the game has ended?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the position of the text inside the label, but in a flow layout (probably the default in your case), it will just wrap the text, so you don't see a difference. You also need to take care of where the label is positioned within the container. In Swing, this is typically done with a layout manager (see also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel ("Count !!", JLabel.CENTER);
label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add (label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

For debugging, you may want to set different background colors for your components, so you see which space they actually occupy...

Comment: it still at the top left side. doesnt move

Comment: What is the container type? You may need to post more code for people to be able to help.